# Creating a unique index based on a timestamp window in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgresql 9.4. I want to use a unique index to enforce a constraint. Let's say I have a table with the following fields:

```
name varchar not null,
started_on tiemstamp not null,
ended_on timestamp
```

A name is considered active when its `ended_on` is null. A `name` can be used multiple times as long as there are no other `name`s with `ended_on` being null or the window bounded by `started_on` and `ended_on` doesn't coincide with any other windows with that `name`.

If I were to do `select * from table` and get these results (say the timestamps are seconds since epoch):

```
name | started_on | ended_on
-----+------------+---------
asdf |          4 |        5
asdf |          7 |     NULL
```

This would be ok

But this wouldn't be ok:

```
name | started_on | ended_on
-----+------------+---------
asdf |          4 |        5
asdf |          3 |     NULL
```

Having the constraint be unique with `ended_on` being null is the easy part. But I'm unable to figure out how to have the constraint do comparisons with individual `started_on/ended_on` times.

Comment: Have you looked at postgresql's [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html), in particular `tstzrange`, and the "Constraints on Ranges" section?

Comment: I haven't, but this answers my question. Thank you.